# ASP.NET How to open a second popup on close() event of first

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, foreach, popup

I want to open a popup window with some parameters inside and then open a new one (or even more than one) with different parameters, after the user closes the first.

It should be like a `foreach` loop where it waits for the closing event before opening a new window.

*I'm using .NET Framework v3.5.*

```
foreach (object o in ObjectsList)
{
    // Do some stuff...

    // Set query string for popup        
    string queryString = string.Format("Page.aspx?doc={0}, o.ID);

    string urlDownload = Page.ResolveClientUrl(string.Format("~/Path/To/Folder/{0}", queryString));

    string script = string.Format("loadDownload('{0}','_blank',600,600);", urlDownload);

    // Open popup window
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "DocID" + o.ID, script, true);

    // Wait for popup close event before proceeding...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These links might be of good use to you.

http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.com.au/2009/03/how-to-open-modalpopup-inside.html

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/546817/ASP-NET-Popup-Control-Displaying-as-multiple-neste

Comment: This is not my case. I don't need to open them nested, but one by one, after closing the previous.

Comment: Hide the first one and then load the 2nd. Try with second example.

Answer (score 0):

I would have registered to the Closed/disposed event and handle all there, that means

```
 ObjectsList
```

will be an instance of your class, where you have an indexer, let say i which tells you in which you are:

```
int i

void frm_disposed(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   showFrm(ObjectsList[++i];
}
```